# I'm getting error in my react code im using firebase storage while im passing the thumbnail value and it has name property on that object, error givin

Tags: reactjs, firebase

`
useForm.js:

```
import { projectStorage } from '../firebase/config';
import { useAuth } from './useAuth';

export const useForm = () => {
  const { user } = useAuth();
  const uploadImage = async (thumbnail) => {
    const uploadPath = `thumbnails/${user.uid}/${thumbnail.name}`;
    try {
      const img = await projectStorage.ref(uploadPath).put(thumbnail);
      const imgUrl = await img.ref.getDownloadURL();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
  };
  return { uploadImage };
};`
```

Form.jsx:
`

```
   import { useState } from "react"
import { useForm} from '../hooks/useForm'

export default function Form() {
    const [caption, setCaption] = useState('')
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)
    const [thumbnail, setThumbnail] = useState(null)
    const { uploadImage} = useForm()

        const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
            e.preventDefault()
          uploadImage(thumbnail)
        }
        
    const handleChange = (e) =>{
        setThumbnail(null)
        const selected = e.target.files[0]
        console.log(selected);
        
        if(!selected){
            setError('please select a file')
            return
        }   
        if(!selected.type.includes('image')){
            setError('please select a image file')
            return
        }

        setError(null)
        setThumbnail(selected)
        console.log('photo updated');
    }

   
  return (
    <div className="add-form">
        <form onClick={handleSubmit}>
            <label>
                <span>Photo:</span>
                <input type="file"  name="file" id="file"  onChange={handleChange} required/>
            </label>
            <label >
                <span>caption:</span>
                <textarea name="captiom" id="caption" onChange={(e)=>setCaption(e.target.value)}></textarea>
                { error && <p className="error">{Error}</p>}
            </label>
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

`
The above is my code in that useForm.js im using that thumbnail state which is stored in form.jsx and passign through the function to useForm.js so i can create path using that to upload images in firebase storage.

useForm.js:7 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name') getting this error

can someone please help me with what I'm doing wrong please give me the solution

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, before posting please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. In particular:
1. Always post error messages as code-formatted text, not images:
2. Please post a minimal reproducible code example. We can't debug code we can't see.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is happening because you aren't validating that `thumbnail` is actually set inside the `handleSubmit` function.

So when it reaches this line:

```
const uploadPath = `thumbnails/${user.uid}/${thumbnail.name}`;
```

...it can't read `.name` because `thumbnail` is null.

---

Try handling the case where `thumbnail` is being submitted as `null` like this:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
  e.preventDefault();
  if(!thumbnail){
    setError('please select a file');
    return;
  }
  setError(null);
  uploadImage(thumbnail);
}
```

Comment: it is not working : Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it. getting this error

Comment: I think it's this line: `{ error && <p className="error">{Error}</p>}`. Make sure you're referencing your error variable with lowercase `{error}` and not a javascript Error object with the uppercase spelling. Try that and let me know if it works.

Comment: no its not im still getting that cannot read properties of null (name)

Comment: And another thing: your `<form onClick={handleSubmit}>` should actually be `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>`.